# Is there a function to negate a binary number in C?

Tags: c, binary, integer

I have the following binary number

```
uint64_t = 0b0100;
```

And I want to negate it to

```
0b1011
```

This is a specific example but I want it to work for any binary number variable. For example,

`uint64_t a`

So is there a function like negate that would make the following true

```
a == negate(negate(a));
```

Comment: 0b0100 isn't legal C. Also, what you're asking about is called inversion or complementing to 1. It may or may not be negation in C because C allows multiple representations of negative integers and the most common is the 2's complement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the [bitwise negation operator](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4ab.html):

```
bar = ~bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the operator ~ ?

```
A = ~B; // A has the 1's complement of B
```